# Remove part of String after .com

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some String say Manchester/United .

In this I want to take this part "United" alone in another String using javascript

I have tried something like this but its returning me Manchester I want United

```
var linkUrl='Manchester/United';
var exampleUrl = 'http://www.exampleurl.com';
if (linkUrl.indexOf(exampleUrl) > -1)
{
    //Code to get United this from linkUrl
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try javascript .match() and use a regular expression to match after the forward slash

Comment: there is no jquery involved... pls remove the tag! there is no html5 involved.... pls remove the tag! why do you search for exampleurl in linkUrl? what do you expect? pls describe your target a bit better with a full example and what you expect.

Comment: Am I missing something, what has manchester united got to do with a string that says exampleurl.com, and whats after .com in the title got to do with anything.  Please rewrite your question as succinctly as possible.

Comment: I totally agree with @TobyAllen

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to split by slash?

```
linkUrl.split("/")[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you need is `linkUrl.match(/[^\/]+$/)`